# Aerospike kafka source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, aerospike

i have setup Aerospike with all the configuration required for Kakfa and m using confluent local cluster for Kafka and have installed https://www.confluent.io/hub/aerospike/kafka-connect-aerospike-source and have started confluent cluster but still connector is not starting

also i found that there is no jar in share folder of confluent is it still under development ?

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? What commands are you using? What do your config files look like? Exactly what JAR are you looking for?

Comment: So to load the connector in confluent for sink command used is
<kafka-dir>/bin/connect-standalone.sh <path-to-your-Kafka-Connect-config-file>  <path to aerospike-sink.properties>  which is fine but for outbound there is no .properties file to load connector file i juts have .yml file then how to load outbound connector

Comment: Connect itself does not use YAML files, so I'm not sure about that. Are you asking how to get data into Kafka? You'd write a producer. Otherwise, you can use `FileSource` connector... That has nothing to do with Aerospike, but the link you have here is [a source connector](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/connect/streaming-from-asdb/from-asdb-to-kafka-overview.html), so why are you mentioning `aerospike-sink.properties`?

Comment: M mentioning as an example that sink connector have aerospike-sink.properties file in it which help to start sink connector but for outbound it has just aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml so can you help me how to start source/outbound connector for aerospike just starting the confluent doesn't start the connector so we can load it afterward so how can we do it if .propertiers file is not present for outbound/source

Comment: I think you should use `connect-distributed.sh`, [as the Aerospike documentation shows](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/connect/streaming/kafka/outbound/index.html), not `confluent` commands. For a more specific answer, I suggest posting to the Aerospike Forums

Comment: Thanks. Even aerospike Solution Architect specified same "I’m told that the Confluent Hub doesn’t install the outbound connector as it only supports a ‘pull’ based model. Apparently what’s installed is some sort of dummy connector. " they will check and update the docs as well

Comment: IMO, that's on them since to upload to Confluent Hub, it's just a ZIP file

Answer (score 2):

It works and is fully generally available but requires extra licensing on the Aerospike side.  I would not expect it to work with Community Edition.

Comment: Ok thanks so the trial version won't work in my case